# Furniture repair off topic?

Tags: discussion

Can someone please clarify why https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/25025/how-to-fix-a-recliner-that-wont-close is off topic?  There are several other questions regarding furniture repair.  What makes this one different?

Comment: Just because it's off topic for the site doesn't mean you can't talk about it in the chat room. There tend to be a few people hanging around during the day, and we try to gather every Thursday at 3pm EST.

Answer (score 9):

Furniture is a bit of a gray area. The core of the site is mostly around parts of your home that were there when you purchased it, the structure, utilities, and major appliances. The one exception that the community added was woodworking, which is how some furniture questions stay on topic. And many of the others are general enough to be applicable to other areas that are on topic. E.g. a squeaky bed frame could be any metal squeak, and a question on the wood finish could also be useful for someone with wood floors.

The question on the mechanics of a recliner is a bit more like the small appliance and hobby project questions that we've made off topic. It requires knowledge about a specific model of a product that isn't part of your home, and the answers probably wouldn't be helpful to others working on home projects. The community decided not to expand the scope because there are lots of possible objects inside the home, an infinite number of hobby projects, and too few of us are experts in them. If we left them on topic, DIY could follow the personal electronics SE proposal, lots of questions, no good answers, no core community, and eventually a closed SE.

Comment: The core of the site is mostly around parts of your home that were there when you purchased it, the structure, utilities, and major appliances." That sentence would be highly useful in the faq or about page.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt Good point. I'll run it past the community to be sure I'm not talking out of place and get that updated in a few days.