# Defining the site scope

Tags: discussion, scope

In [another meta question](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/754/2196), I mentioned "The core of the site is mostly around parts of your home that were there when you purchased it, the structure, utilities, and major appliances." That leads to two questions. First, was I speaking out of place, or does everyone agree that this is a decent starting point when describing our scope? And second, if that description is a good summary, are there any objections to adding something along those lines to the top of our FAQ and About pages?

Comment: Wikipedia has a good description of [Home Improvement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_improvement). "*While "home improvement" often refers to building projects that alter the structure of an existing home, it can also include improvements to* ... *outdoor structures, such as gazebos and garages. It also encompasses maintenance, repair and general servicing tasks.*"

Comment: @Tester: But then we get into Gardening.SE

Comment: See edited comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like a useful addition to the FAQ (and indeed about page) - perhaps replacing some (or indeed all) of the bullet points we currently have.

I think it defines the distinction between what's on and off topic quite clearly. There will be questions where there is dispute over which side of the line they lie, but hopefully it should be more obvious more of the time.

Comment: I concur. While I think 2-3 example bullets can help (er) hammer the point home, the succinct sentence would go a long way.

Answer (score 2):

So building an addition, a deck, outbuilding, etc. would not fall within the site's scope?

Comment: I think that's definitely in-scope!

Comment: Agreed, this would certainly be in scope. If you've got suggestions on how to reword the headline to make it more clear, I'm all ears.

Comment: "there when you purchased and added after (or plan to add)" but now it's just sounding long-winded haha

Comment: Now I'm thinking: "The core of the site is mostly around parts of your home that are typically included when you buy or sell it, the structure, utilities, and major appliances."

Comment: +1 not because I think those were out of scope, but because you raised a good point. Thanks decker.