# Is furniture assembly off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

We've seen a few furniture assembly questions lately that are in a gray area for me. I'm incline to close them, but want to be sure that the community agrees.

Two examples:

- [IKEA table problem](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/40859/2196)
- [Assembling the springs in a double-bed](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/40835/2196)

From the [prior question about furniture repair](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/754/2196), I had indicated that my view of the scope is that woodworking is on topic where some furniture questions get allowed. And questions that can apply to other home improvement tasks would be on topic not because of the furniture component, but due to their general home improvement applications. Should we directly state that furniture assembly is off topic, or are these questions a useful addition?

Comment: One is about IKEA furniture, which has some of the best, most accessible documentation. The other has ASCII art, which I personally hate (especially since the site allows images). I say close them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Furniture assembly is not really DIY, so these questions are off topic.

Comment: The reasoning could stand some clarification here. It absolutely _is_ DIY. It may not be _home improvement_, but it's doing something yourself instead of paying for the service.